# Reference value of text column in SELECT statement's TOP part

Tags: sql, ms-access

How can I use a numerical value of a text column of a form in the `TOP` part of a `SELECT` statement?

I have this statement:

```
SELECT TOP [Forms]![frmPersons]![txtPersonCount] tblPersons.ID AS Person
FROM tblPersons
ORDER BY tblPersons.Rating
```

I tried it this way but couldn't get it to work. I get the error of using a reserved word.

I'd like to have it so, that you can get the X TOP results where X is the number entered in txtPersonCount.

Comment: You can't do this with regular Access SQL.  You would need to somehow build the query dynamically, either using Access directly or maybe VBA.

Comment: Build the SQL statement in VBA and set the RecordSource property of a form or report or use QueryDef to modify query object.